# Free Space is not detected

Tags: dual-boot, disk-usage

Recently started using Ubuntu 22.04. I want to copy files from a flash disk (about 5 GB)
but OS states not enough space. However, I can see from the terminal and from the partitions manager that more than 200 GB are available.

Screenshot 1:[image]

Screenshot 2:
[image]

Comment: You didn't tell us how you try to copy these files, what is the method you use, which commands?

Comment: Direct copy paste (as in windows)

Comment: Please try from command line and [edit] your question to add the error messages you get this time.

Comment: If you are using fat32, then try formatting it to exFAT.